# Implementing HTTP etags in Spring WebFlux controller

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, etag, optimistic-locking, if-modified-since

For Spring MVC there is a very nice and straight-forward way to implement etags in response headers (https://www.baeldung.com/etags-for-rest-with-spring), however cant find something similar for Web Flux (with reactive controllers). Anyone know if this is supported?

Basically I want my controller

```
  @GetMapping("/{student_id}")
  Mono<Student> getStudentBydId(@PathVariable String studentId) {
    return studentService.getStudentBydId(studentId);
  }
```

to attach an etag header for every entity that is returned, and allow for usage of `If-Modified` header.